# Java: precision error using long and int

Tags: java, long-integer, precision

(Still) a newbie in Java, trying to work with `long` and `int` values. I'm trying to deduct 1 from a long value and it keeps telling me there's a possible loss of error?

I looked at other questions but all the ones I saw addressed either `float` precision errors or people did not know why they were using `long` instead of `int`. In my case, it is required in the question I'm given.

```
    String bookingRequest = "";
    int bookingElements = 4;
    String[] bookingDetails = new String[bookingElements];
    long seatNo = 0;
    for(int x = 1; x <= counter; x++) {
        bookingRequest = input.nextLine();
        bookingDetails = bookingRequest.split(" ");
        seatNo = Long.parseLong(bookingDetails[0]);
        seatHolders[seatNo - 1] = bookingDetails[1] + " " + bookingDetails[2] + " " + bookingDetails[3];
    }

//  A bit of code later
    long check = 0;
    for (long c = 1; c <= seatChecker; c++) {
        check = input.nextLong();
        //System.out.println(seatHolders[check - 1]);
        seatFinder[c - 1] = seatHolders[check - 1];
    }
```

I do know that there is most probably a better way of writing this code, but as I have to use a `long` data type to take in the seat number (as according to the question), I only really need to know why it doesn't like minusing one from `long` values.

The error:

```
Test.java:22: error: possible loss of precision
                        seatHolders[seatNo - 1] = bookingDetails[1] + " " + book
ingDetails[2] + " " + bookingDetails[3];
                                           ^
  required: int
  found:    long
Test.java:31: error: possible loss of precision
                        seatFinder[c - 1] = seatHolders[check - 1];
                                     ^
  required: int
  found:    long
Test.java:31: error: possible loss of precision
                        seatFinder[c - 1] = seatHolders[check - 1];
                                                              ^
  required: int
  found:    long
3 errors
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: [Why does array index have to be an integer?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/455957/java/java/array-index-integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array indexes must be an `int` values, but when you subtract from `long`, the result is also `long`. You must either change variable from long to int, or cast the subtraction result to `int`, e.g.:

```
for (int c = 0; c < ...; c++) {
  check = input.nextLong();
  seatFinder[c - 1] = seatHolders[(int)(check - 1)];
}
```

Or:

```
for (long c = 0; c < ...; c++) {
  check = input.nextLong();
  seatFinder[(int)(c - 1)] = seatHolders[(int)(check - 1)];
}
```

But please note that casting to `int` will result in value truncation in case when the value is greater than `int` range.

Comment: Thank you! :) Solved my problem! The value isn't greater than the int range. The max value is actually 1000, which is why I'm going to the lecturer tomorrow to ask why we need a `long` value if `int` can hold the value. Thanks again! :D

Answer (score 2):

The  variables  contained  in  an array are referenced by array access expressions that
use **non-negative integer index values**. That is why, If you even try to use `long` as index, it will try to convert the 64-bit `long`  to 32-bit `int` and hence loss of precision may result. The compiler is letting you to know it.

Answer (score 2):

Every index that you are using is `int` and then you are attempting to use `long` arithmetics to access the elements - so the compiler warns you about loss of precision (significant digits) when converting larger `long` to 'int'

Answer (score 1):

Array index in Java must be int. That is why the compiler complains when you use long, it has to cast it to int.